# Warning messages from Blockly

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, blockly

I have an Angular app running with Blockly. Most of times it goes well, however every time I run it I have a bunch of messages like these two types:

```
`/Components/blockly/blockly.component.ts depends on 'blockly/core'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts`.
```

I know how to deactivate this messages in the angular.json, but I don't know why Blockly can cause optimization bailouts. And even if I deactivate the message the bailouts can still occur. I don't know if it's something about the injection as I used this:

```
 import * as Blockly from 'blockly/core';
```

when I don't use the default blocks. Is it a better way to import?

The other messages are like this type:

```
blockly compressed.js:40 No message string for %{BKY_MATH_SINGLE_TOOLTIP_LOG10} in %{BKY_MATH_SINGLE_TOOLTIP_LOG10}
```

Every time they appear something doesn't go as it has to go. Any idea of this? I read a GitHub post about it but it wasn't clear for me.

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the bailout issue.

For the `No message string for x` errors, you should import the language files. For example:

```
import en from 'blockly/msg/en';

// Then use the language file
Blockly.setLocale(en);
```

However this should only be necessary if you're using any of the default blocks. Is this the case? If not, are you importing Blockly correctly everywhere?

Comment: Hello, I imported it like this:
 `import * as Blockly from 'blockly/core;`